# Matomo - visits log filter by browser version

Tags: matomo

I am trying to retrieve information of all the visitor's browser info(especially the browser versions). Is this possible to filter logs based on this criteria?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the Matomo Segments feature.

So for example you can create a new segment in Matomo using the following for example:

```
Browser Is Firefox
and
Browser version Is 300.2
```

This segment can then be applied to the Visits Log to see all visits from people that used Firefox version 300.2 when visiting your website.

You can find out more in the Matomo Segmentation guide here: https://matomo.org/docs/segmentation/